# Problems with iOS 13 and Cordova App not Scrolling

Tags: ios, cordova, kendo-ui, wkwebview, kendo-mobile

I have a Cordova App using Kendo-ui and Kendo-mobile and ever since the release of iOS 13 none of my views will scroll at all.

This issue was not present in iOS Beta which scrolls fine

I am using `WKWebview` from the `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview` plugin which fixed some scrolling issues I was having a few months ago in the iOS 12.4 release

Have tried the following

Updating Kendo-ui to latest version

Adding the preferences for the ionic webview plugin as follows

```
preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="true" 

preference name="WKSuspendInBackground" value="false"
```

I was wondering if anyone else has experienced this over the last few days since iOS 13 has been rolling out.

Comment: Having the same issue with just kendo-ui (no cordova)

Comment: @jinksPadlock that's good to know that I can start to narrow it down to Kendo-ui. Have you found any clues yet? I have tried switching to native scroll = true for the kendo mobile setup but that doesn't work either

Comment: @jinksPadlock actually just realized I already had native scrolling on via a different method which was overriding my test and turning off native scrolling actually fixed the issue. But now I have to figure out a way to re-implement my infinite scroll that only worked with native scrolling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause of my problems here.

The issue with is Kendo's ListView control not scrolling.

I don't know the root cause of Kendo's issues but I think most likely an issue with Webkit as it only happens with the WKWebview not the UIWebview.

There is an issue open on the repository https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/5276

Luckily for me I was only really using the Kendo ListView's as containers for styling so for now I have just re-implemented them with divs and handled the styling by using kendo style classes manually.